# A piece of soil actually landed on the PCB on my hard drive

Tags: installation, hardware-failure

I was installing some new hardware in my computer when I looked down and noticed a small pile of soil around the size of a BB pellet (the computer was not on when this happened.)  Can soil discharge static electricity?

Comment: No;  It cannot..

Comment: Depends on the composition of the soil.

Comment: It should be fine. Test the drive and see if there are any issues.

Answer (score 4):

1) Your hard drive (and computer itself) are not as fragile as you think they are, although some caution is always required.

2) Did you have the cover of the HARD DRIVE removed to expose the internals of the drive? I would bet not, dust and dirt on the outside of a hard drive are completely normal, that is why the drive is sealed.

3) Can soil discharge static electricity? sure, look at lightning, but I don't think this is a real issue in your case.

Blow out the dust/dirt... Are you having any problems? No? Go about your everyday life.

Trust me, a computer can work fine with dirt, lots of it... See [these pictures](https://www.google.com/search?q=dirty%20computer&espv=2&biw=1364&bih=929&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiq6dr5gebKAhUU5WMKHZaNDzoQ_AUIBigB), this is more common that you would think. You have no idea how some computers function when you can take cups or liters of dirt out of them, and that's not even the problem, they were happily chugging along doing their job.

And static electricity can always be an issue, but modern components can take some level of abuse in this regard with no problems.

Comment: Sorry. I meant to include this in my description, the dirt landed on the PCB.

Comment: @Matt Still not relevant except in extremely unusual circumstances... Did you look at any of the pictures? Like I said, your computer is not as fragile as you think it is.

Comment: @Matt I'm sure your fine, just keep up normal maintenance... Periodically blow the dirt and dust buildup out of fans, heatsinks, power supply, and other components and you will be fine, how often varies on environment, but I typically clean out my personal PCs about 2-3 times per year or when I start to notice dust buildup on air intake areas.

Comment: What unusual circumstances are you implying?

Comment: Honestly, the conditions would be so unusual I can't think of any.